# Cannot send ajax request to other domain - Angular js

Tags: angularjs, cors

How can we perform cross site ajax request from angular js? I have tried doing in this way:

```
$http.post('http://cross.local', data)
```

But the browser is throwing an error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access.

So i added the headers

> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

But I'm still getting the same error.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You will need to show the request headers according to a reliable proxy, along with the response headers.

Comment: When you say you added the headers, do you mean to the request or to the response?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the CORS support in Angular, which is off by default

```
yourApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
]);
```

The first line enables the CORS support, the second removes the header that typically is send with Ajax requests.

If you do not want this behavior everywhere in your app, you need to fine tune where to set the defaults.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked for 'get' request but not for post request

Comment: Maybe you to do an GET request before you first POST request to make sure the browser has the right headers cached.

Comment: sorry, i didnt understand what you said.

Comment: I have seen you post this answer at least a couple times. At best, it's only half-right.  First, the `useXDomain` option doesn't exist in Angular, and, if it did, it would only apply to IE9 and IE8, and it would require inclusion of a wrapper for `XDomainRequest`, which Angular also doesn't do. Second, removing the X header is not necessary. Cross-domain requests are still possible with it. Removing this header just lessens the chance of the request being preflighted, but it still may be anyway if it is not a "simple" req. Generally, cross-domain support is a server issue, not a client one.

Answer (score 0):

In the server i forget to add the handler for POST request, So for each post request 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access.' error is thrown by the server. When i added the POST handler it worked